# How to install sublime text for typescript in ubuntu

Tags: command-line, sublime-text

I have followed this following command to install sublime text editor

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer
```

I have successfully installed sublime

**problem :**

> I am not getting as using the typescript. in order to update my sublime to work with type script what i should i'm struck here. Appearance of my sublimetext with angular 2 is not good.
>
> i am working on angular2 and typescript. I followed the offical website [github for downloading typescript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Sublime-Plugin) and downloaded the sublime text editor for typescript .

Answer (score 2):

You dont have to download a separate version of sublime text to get typescript support.You only need to install the package manager from [here](https://packagecontrol.io/installation). And then after opening sublime text press `Shift +Ctrl+P` type install there select install a package from the drop down and then search for typescript to install typescript.[image]
You can follow this tutorial typescript support for sublimetext3 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2iRHiDgOsJA